# What is infecting these networks between 10/25/15 and 11/1/15?

Tags: google, security, spam, malware

Just noticed a [fancy new graphical threat dashboard](https://www.google.com/transparencyreport/safebrowsing/malware/?hl=en#region=ALL&period=90&size=LARGEST&compromised&attack&asn=35916&aggregation=COUNT&page=1) in the Google malware scan systems. There seems to be a cleanup then subsequent spike in infected sites across various [less-than-high-quality] Hosts/ASN's starting aprx 10/25/15. Is this a Google scanner/view error, is there something nefarious going around infecting hosts/accounts lately, or are they simply that full of replicating spam/mal/adware?

Example graph showing the dip and subsequent spike of infected sites. More than 1 top infected ASN's show a similar trend of a dip N rise.

[image: Google malware scan 2014-2015]

Example graph showing one of the few with a similar spike of attacking sites. I didn't see others with this trend per-say.

[image: Google malware scan 2014-2015]

Note: if the above link doesn't work you can find it via `Google transparency report portal > safe browsing > malware dashboard (sidebar)`.

Comment: Believe it or not, hackers take time off. They usually work at night and weekdays. ;-) Also, I rather suspect that some of this is happenstance. One of the traits is that a single hacker will effect thousands on less secure and permissive networks. Sometimes these attacks are targeted by IP range(s) and sometimes it is as random as any bot would be. Also infected systems tend to attack other systems more locally by IP address. What is also true is that there are far less hackers out there than people think. Often, it is just a few people at a time letting alone the really sophisticated stuff.

Comment: @closetnoc Hah I'm assuming it to be cross account related and auto replicating -- whereas the hosts may not use cages/jails/isolation for their tenants, they may allow PHP to run stuff in other users areas, full bash may be available to peons, too many cmd's available to peons/groups, the "hosting company" (cough...reseller) is run by 13 year olds ....... etc. Just curious if there is a certain strain of something making the rounds, because these spikes across the board make it seem like something is quite good at multiplying itself once it's injected via whatever vector.

Comment: The business of web hosting is almost universal. There is no firewall, intrusion detection, no anti-virus, no jail, no app firewalls, full access to the PHP environment, etc. There is no policing what is installed, monitoring traffic patterns, nothing. Script kiddie stuff goes around most days in waves and infects huge amounts of computers both web host and subscriber line. The spread is very rapid. Most is aimed at Wordpress or MS clients. It gets crazy.

Comment: @closetnoc Haha aye. Its very surprising sometimes what hosts dont know they are doing. Example, I logged into a shared server the other day on a top tier, fully jailed up host running Cloudlinux + cPanel. Surprisingly i could SSH and run cmds that i shouldnt have been able to. Example `# cat /etc/passwd` worked (showed handfuls of other users with full shell), moving to other home dirs worked, files (ie config.php's) could be cat, or at the least copied out to my dir. Wtf, ya know? This isnt a sysadmin, its just a shared accnt. I reported it to them and they acted like it was totally cool.

Comment: @closetnoc aaaannnddd to boot, many hosts allow wacky stuff like this to actually work as a total site spoof, as long as you can find the username in /etc/passwd or `top` - `www.mysite.com/~someotheraccount/dir` so its def not surprising the state we are in, just super curious what the strand of malware is :)

Comment: I was a web host years ago and charged the industry standard rate of less than $10. I at the time was also a core network engineer for a global telecom and managed nearly 1000 servers on the Internet for them. I had the best connectivity in the world, 2 redundant OC3s to MAEEAST and 2 redundant OC3s to MAEWEST with another 2 redundant OC3 clear routing backbone accesses, and 3 satellite accesses. I managed tight systems with full firewall, anti-virus, anti-spam, fully jailed accounts all to the highest level possible. And yet, people wanted free accounts or very cheap accounts. Silly sh**s!

Comment: I also wrote an app that monitored installed web apps in each website and jailed vulnerable web apps preventing their access and use with a notice to the site owner. I helped them fix it myself so that they got what they wanted in a safe way. I also blocked common bad accesses as a web app firewall before these things existed. My firewall was a deep packet inspection firewall and allowed full HTTP filtering which I used. I even wrote my own SMTP anti-virus and anti-spam filters. I had 100% success in fighting spam and viruses. It is possible if people would just give a ding dang.

Comment: @closetnoc Dude....that is awesome! Sounds like you have seen it seen it, i give you knuckles sir. That app monitor would be very useful on top of other audits like file, stamp, etc.